# Customizing lightning:combobox component

Tags: lightning-aura-components

When lightning:combobox is rendered in browser, using developer console, you will find the HTML code:

```
<ul id="input-1-listbox" role="listbox" class="slds-listbox slds-listbox--vertical slds-dropdown slds-dropdown--fluid slds-dropdown--length-5 slds-dropdown--left">
...
</ul>
```

Is it possible to replace a class with another class? So in the above code, is it possible to replace slds-dropdown--length-5 with slds-dropdown--length-7?

OR

Can I add class slds-dropdown--length-7 so that the HTML markup becomes like below:

```
<ul id="input-1-listbox" role="listbox" class="slds-listbox slds-listbox--vertical slds-dropdown slds-dropdown--fluid slds-dropdown--length-5 slds-dropdown--left slds-dropdown--length-7">
...
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

It appears that this is a future enhancement planned for a future release. There is an undocumented attribute "length" that will generate an exception if you try to use it. For now, if you want a length other than 5, you have to write your own component.

---

```
<lightning:combobox label="Test" options="[{value:1,label:1}]" name="test" length="7" />
```

---

> Assertion Failed!: "length" must either be a public property of lightningCombobox or a global HTML attribute : false

Comment: So in this case, do I need to override a specific class and write my own implementation?

Comment: @snl I'm not sure you can easily CSS your way through it, you would need to write your own custom component.

Answer (score 0):

you can override the css class by using the below code in your css file

```
.THIS .slds-dropdown--length-5 {
  over ride with what ever css elements you want
}
```

for example I see that .slds-dropdown--length-5 css in the salesforce is

```
.slds-dropdown_length-5, .slds-dropdown--length-5 {
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
  max-height: calc(((0.8125rem * 1.5) + 1rem) * 5);
  overflow-y: auto; }
```

if you use

```
 .THIS .slds-dropdown--length-5 {
       -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
  max-height: calc(((0.8125rem * 1.5) + 1rem) * 7);
  overflow-y: auto; 
    }
```

this will solve your problem.

Comment: I have tried this, it doesn't work